# Execute a file in the body of a specific content type

Tags: javascript, theming, nodes

How to load the file, which contains css, javascript and html, in the body of a specific content type?

Comment: The file that contains that is html.tpl.php, but why you need to load that file in a content type? What do you need to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for [Code per Node](https://drupal.org/project/cpn) module:

> Code per Node makes it possible to add custom CSS and Javascript per node, per content type, per block, and globally. The code is stored in the database, but served from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

[Insert](https://drupal.org/project/insert) is a utility that makes inserting images and links to files into text areas or WYSIWYGs much easier. It adds a simple JavaScript-based button to FileField and ImageField widgets.

You can insert files inserted into text areas with a specific Content type Option.

[image]